# I want to merge an unallocated space with my Ubuntu Partition but i can't

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted, lts

I used G-PARTED, the partition managing application, to merge my Ubuntu Installation Partition (sda6) with unallocated space. When I try to increase the Ubuntu partition with the resize option, no extra space is available. How can I enlarge my system partition sda6? [image: Unallocating operation is successful]

Unallocating operation is successful

[image: The Unallocated space is just left of the Ubuntu Partition]

The Drives to be merged are the /dev/sda6 and the unallocated space left of it.

[image: It shows the max and min size same and does not let me merge them]

It shows the max and min size same and does not let me merge them

Comment: See the little 'key' icon by /dev/sda6? That icon means the partition is mounted. Mounted partitions cannot be changed. Boot from a LiveUSB to change your root (/) partition. Also, back up your data first -- re-partitioning is inherently risky.

Comment: boot from g parted live?

Comment: what would happen if i unmnount it? just asking

Comment: You can try. Since it's your root (/) partition, if you succeed your system will immediately crash. Not a wise strategy for safely preserving your data.

Comment: The free space "above" represents nothing, not enough to add it to the partition. Delete sda5 and sda6, creae one big ext4 partition in the free space and move your data there.

Comment: @vanadium You **DON'T** want to delete /dev/sda6.

Comment: @heynnema sd7 indeed, not 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- if you don't need /dev/sda5 then **delete** this partition (there is data on it)
- if you don't need /dev/sda7 then **delete** this partition (there is data on it)
- **move** /dev/sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda6 partition all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Answer (score 2):

It is not trivial to make `sda6` use the free space, because it comes before that partition rather than after it. **A move of `sda6` is therefore required.** This can be a lengthy process that may fail.

Take following steps *from a live session* so none of the partitions on the drive are in use. Do not start this before your backup of your user data is up to date. When manipulating partitions, there is always a risk (human error and/or technical error).

- Remove partition `sda5`;
- Remove partition `sda7`;
- Move your current system partition sda6 to the left into the free space. *This will take a very long time and may fail*;
- Enlarge the moved `sda6` to the right to fill the free space.

A safer and quicker option would be to create a new partition in the free space (after removing `/dev/sda5` and `7`). If you then move out all your user data from system partition /dev/sda6 to that new partition, it will have plenty of free space. This can be done from within your running Ubuntu system.

Comment: sir i am talking about the unallocated space above sda6 which is 117 gb. you have misinterpreted.

Comment: To me, "above" sda6 means "to the right of sda6". You are using confusing terminology.

Comment: OK, I updated the anser to provide the procedure to enlarge sda6. It involves a move, and this is very lengthy and may fail. So be warned.

Answer (score -1):

You can't resize the partition because the unallocated space is not adjacent to the sda6 partition. if you are not using the sda7 partition, then you can delete it and then try to resize the sda6.

Make sure you are not using the sda7 before doing the above and make sure you have backed up your data.