# Can't merge unallocated partition to the Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda6)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Can't seem to resize or expand my Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda6) using GParted, no matter whatsoever.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRpk.png) is the screenshot of my GParted

I used to have Windows 10 installed on the main partition (/dev/sda), which, after installing Ubuntu, I have deleted now from the dual boot.

**Note:** I know a lot of other similar answers exist but none of them have been able to resolve my situation as of now. Please have a look at my *GParted screenshot* before you close this question as a *duplicate*.

**Note2:** Booting Live Ubuntu from USB doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize the root partition using GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430956/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-using-gparted)

Comment: It's mounted (thus the *lock* symbol) and cannot be resized whilst in-use. You need to umount (`umount`) it first, but it's far easier to resize from *live* media.  Boot Ubuntu installation media & use the "*Try Ubuntu*", this will mean it's not in-use and can be easily re-sized.

Comment: Surely you can right-click and "unmount" from the gparted GUI.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Sir, will it not create a problem as it is my root partition and I can't unmount it because the system is currently running off of it ?

Comment: You are posting under different accounts? Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361041/i-want-to-merge-an-unallocated-space-with-my-ubuntu-partition-but-i-cant?noredirect=1#comment2333182_1361041 your issue has been addressed and some people did serious efforts there to write out step by step. You now need to move the partition. That can take a lot of time.

Comment: @vanadium, No, why would I do that? As you can see that person having exactly the same issue has his /dev/sda with 465.76 GiB but I have mine with 931.51 GiB

Comment: My apologies! Could be that you lost the password. However, also the size of the sda6 partition is slightly different but otherwise, the situation is surprisingly similar. Head to Heynnema's answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1361173/558158 read it fully, but for you , you only need to continue on "move /dev/sda6 partition all the way left". Be warned: moving can be slow, and may fail. Personally, I would reinstall fresh in this case.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, thanks a lot for your help. Solved.